# How can I rewire a MainView-iPad.xib to the viewController?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am porting my Phone app to iPad.
I changed my target's "Devices" to `Universal` under "Summary".
I put the conditional `(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)` to determine whether the app is running on iPad.
I created a new `XIB` dedicated for iPad and placed a view in there.

How can I rewire the IBOutlets back into the iPad version of the XIB?

Thanks
[image]

[image]

Comment: Just an observation, since you have three identical answers already and none of them have helped - iirc you can't connect outlets unless the storyboard is zoomed to 100% - often with iPad ones you're a bit zoomed out, to fit it all in. Is that it?

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to define the class of the **File's Owner**:

[image]

Since you create a new XIB, it should be set to `UIViewController`, just select from the list your `UIViewController's` subclass.

The new image:

[image]

---

Just a small detail:

Avoid using this kind of stuff: `(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)`. It completely destroys your application architecture when creating a version for iPad and iPhone of the same application, which share the same code. Just sub-class the class you want. Keep the common code on the parent and the specifics in each sub-class.

Comment: I didn't mention I did that, but the IBOutlets are still not available

Comment: If you only added the XIB, and the `UIViewController` is the same, try cleaning the project and check again.

Comment: What about the file's owner? how do I wire that?

Comment: Check the new image..That's what the file's owner is.

Comment: Still, when I right click the view there's nothing there that I can wire it to...

Comment: Could you take a print screen like the first one i showed you?

Comment: I want to see the same thing as my first print... If you don't provide us with something we can't help...

Comment: If you are able to share the project, I will able to fix it. Because I am bit out of ideas. =/

Answer (score 1):

select "Identity inspector" window on new Xib. 
change class name to your viewController 
then select file owner and your outlet automatically show up

there is the Controller class is same for both Xib

Comment: @ Ted it must be happen Did you attach View Controller in right way ?

Comment: I commented above that I did that already. Yet, the IBOutlets are not showing.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to rewrite any `IBOutlets`. But just assign the proper class to the xib's file owner and all the `IBOutlets` of that class is available to you and as you have used them in iPhone xib use them for iPad's xib.

Happy Coding :)